# PHP close MySQL connection

Tags: php, mysql, connection

I have a file config.php

```
<?php

$dbhost = "*****";
$dbname = "*****";
$dbuser = "*****";
$dbpassword = "*****";

$connect = mysql_connect("$dbhost","$dbuser","$dbpassword");
mysql_select_db("$dbname",$connect);

mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf-8'");
?>
```

And i have file insert.php with inserting form values into MySql.
At the end of this file i am trying to close database connection with:

```
mysql_close($connection);
```

but it gives me error, please advise.

P.S: I am very new to php so please don't blame.

Comment: Mixing mysql with mysqli!!

Comment: Additionally, using `$connect` and `$connection`?

Comment: what is the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `mysqli_close($connect)` instead of `mysql_close($connect);`

```
$connect = mysql_connect("$dbhost","$dbuser","$dbpassword");
mysql_close($connect);
```

I would suggest you to move your code to `mysqli` because `mysql` is not supported anymore in `php7`

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
mysql_close($connect);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use mysqli because mysql is not supported anymore in PHP latest version. and you are trying to  close database connection with mysqli.
  use like this.

```
mysql_close($connect);
```